# BQ load from csv file stored in storage using java client

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-bigquery-java

Tried to load into existing BQ table from csv file stored in the bucket using google BQ client but ran into this error. Not sure how can I figure out this position in the csv file. I replaced all the NULL strings with "" values and also surrounding each column with double quote. Thougth I solved all issues but ran into this issue and don't know how to get around it. Any help would be appreciated.

> "com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error while reading
> data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at
> position: 178031. Error: Data between close double quote (") and field
> separator. File: gs://merch-meter/Merch-Meter-jira-issues-03-31-2023"

This is the code that generates a row in the csv file

```
public static String createCsvRecord(Issue issue) {
        String sprintstartdate = (issue.getSprintstartdate() == null) ? "" : DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(issue.getSprintstartdate());
        String sprintenddate = (issue.getSprintenddate() == null) ? "" : DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(issue.getSprintenddate());
        String createddate = (issue.getCreateddate() == null) ? "" : DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(issue.getCreateddate());
        String completeddate = (issue.getCompleteddate() == null) ? "" : DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(issue.getCompleteddate());
        String lastupdateddate = (issue.getLastupdateddate() == null) ? "" : DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(issue.getLastupdateddate());
        String issueName = Utils.escapeSpecialCharacters(issue.getIssueName());
        String parentId = StringUtils.isNotBlank(issue.getParentId())? issue.getParentId():"";
        String parentType = StringUtils.isNotBlank(issue.getParentType())? issue.getParentType():"";
        String lastUpdatedUser = StringUtils.isNotBlank(issue.getLastupdateduser()) &&
                !issue.getLastupdateduser().equalsIgnoreCase("null")? issue.getLastupdateduser():"";
        String labels = Utils.escapeSpecialCharacters(issue.getLabels());
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(issueName) && StringUtils.contains(issueName, ","))
            issueName = issueName.replace(",", " ");

        StringBuilder csvStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getTeamid()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getJiraboardid()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getIssueid()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getIssuetype()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getSprintId()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getStatus()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(createddate).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(completeddate).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(sprintstartdate).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(sprintenddate).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(lastUpdatedUser).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(lastupdateddate).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getIssuepoints().intValue()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getCreator_emailAddress()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getCreator_displayName()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getCreator_accountId()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.isCreator_isActive()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.getComponents()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(labels).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issueName).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(parentId).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(parentType).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(issue.isDeleted()).append("\",");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\"").append(DateUtil.getUtcDatetime(new Date())).append("\"");
        csvStringBuilder.append("\n");
        return csvStringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Let me know if you need the csv file and will upload it to G drive after redacting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with escaping double quotes in the csv file. They need to be escaped with another double quotes for double quotes inside the csv field.

> "PagerDuty - Research adding attachments to \"Create PD Incident\" shortcut"

they have to be replaced with the below field

> "PagerDuty - Research adding attachments to ""Create PD Incident"" shortcut"